# Java EE/wildfly spending a lot of time outside of core application

Tags: java, profiling, wildfly

I am trying to profile my application and figure out why it is slow and if there are any ways to improve the performance.
So, I've tested the profiler JProfile and connected it to the correct JVM.
When I look at the call tree I see that my code is in the minority when it comes to execution time.

So either I am missunderstanding the call graph or something is broken.
[image: call graph]

So is that behaviour normal? (on a wildfly server)

Comment: It's not really possible to see anything from the screenshot. Try setting the filters to your own packages only in the session settings and check the percentage in the top-level "run" node. That is the time that is spent in the container before your classes are called.

Comment: @IngoKegel I've filtered by package and the percentage is down to 85%, so am I interpreting it correctly if i say that 85% is my application and 15% is the app server? and would that be normal or is it cause for concern?

Comment: Difficult to say in general. If there are a lot of requests and the requests themselves take very little time, then the container may take a substantial amount of time itself.